# Creating shape or marks in custom indicator, (tradingview charting library (pinejs))

Tags: react-native, charts, pine-script, trading, tradingview-api

is there any way to create shape or create marks on chart in custom indicator using tradingview charting library. [I am using this way to create custom indicators](https://github.com/serdimoa/charting/wiki/Creating-Custom-Studies).   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does anyone have an answer to this question?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Here is the guide.
For the callouts/Markers on chart you can follow this guide in the JS API.
https://github.com/tradingview/charting_library/wiki/JS-Api#gettimescalemarkssymbolinfo-from-to-ondatacallback-resolution

For **getmarks** you can do this

```
 getMarks: (symbolInfo, startDate, endDate, onDataCallback, resolution) => {
    var Arr = [   
      {
        id: 1,
        time: 1551448800000 / 1000,
        color: 'blue',
        text: 'Hello world',
        label: 'B',
        labelFontColor: 'yellow',
        minSize: 20        
      },      
  ]
  onDataCallback(Arr);
    
    console.log("=====getMarks running");
  },
```

It will plot the marks above the bars as shown in the below image.

[image]

For **Timescalemarks**.

```
  getTimescaleMarks: (symbolInfo,startDate,endDate,onDataCallback,resolution) => {
onDataCallback([   
          {
            id: 1,
            time:  / 1000,
            color: 'Turquoise',
            label: 'The test you want to show on marker',
            minSize: 20,
            tooltip:[
              "Information you want to print",
            ]
          },
        ]);
})
```

The Time scale marks will look like this. And they will be plotted below the bars.

[image]

And for the shapes like circles and arrows you can follow this documentation. And use the **createMultipointShape(points, options)** methos to plot your shapes.

https://github.com/tradingview/charting_library/wiki/Chart-Methods#createmultipointshapepoints-options

Comment: Can I pull those from chart to Javascript? Like a callback when OnClick on candles or creating those callouts/shapes?

Comment: Well I think you can do it. These are the JS APIS that you need to call. And you can even call them on and the event also.

Comment: the shapes from createMultipointShape() won't disappear if you remove or hide the custom indicators.

Comment: There is a method you need to call on removal or while hiding the indicators. 
Clear/remove the callouts/markers
  tvWidget.chart().clearMarks();

Remove the Text shapes
tvWidget.chart().removeEntity(ShapeID)